# "It is through experiences that you experience the world." - avoid repetition

Tags: repetition

"It is through experiences that you experience the world."

How can I say the same phrase, either replacing the world "experiences" or "experience"? I was thinking "It is through experiences that you live the world.", but does it make sense?

Thank you!

Comment: *It is through "travelling" that you experience the world*, *It is through "reading" that you experience*..., or *It is through "love"....* It depends on the type of message you want to convey. But there's nothing wrong with the original sentence because *experience* is being used first as a noun and then as a verb, so it's not really redundant. It's an effective sentence. Could you say "why" you need to change one of them?

Comment: I agree with Mari-Lou A.  It is an effective sentence as it is.  It is effective because of the repetition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.  If English is not your first language, maybe you would want to figure out first what you want to say in your first language and find the translation afterwards.  That way you can make sure that the choice of words accurately conveys the meaning you have in mind.

As suggestions, I would say:

- It is through experience that you know the world, or
- It is through experience that you learn about the world.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

How about... ?

> It is through experiences that you ***know*** the world.

Repetition is not always a bad thing though, it can be used to highlight a contrast. With a bit of a tweak I think it's okay here.

> It is only through experiences, that you experience the world.
>   It is only through the experienced moment, that you experience the world.

Answer (score 0):

"It is through experiences that you perceive the world."